# Where Can I store my Tablespaces' datafiles using AWS?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, tablespace, data-files

Im supposed to create database for a project. Finally decided to use AWS RD using Oracle so we can all can connect to the same database and use the same information available in the application.

Now doing a little research, I am supposed to create a directory for my table spaces

```
CREATE TABLESPACE GE_Ind
       DATAFILE 'C:\app\name\oradata\demo\geind01.dbf'
       SIZE 10M
       REUSE
       AUTOEXTEND ON
       NEXT 512K
       MAXSIZE 200M;
```

What happens is that RDS does not allow users to manipulate directories like this. it says
 *"Amazon RDS only supports Oracle Managed Files (OMF) for data files, log files and control files. When creating data files and log files you cannot specify physical file names."*
Is there any other way in which i can achieve what i want using this AWS resource? is there any other option availble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify a datafile on Amazon RDS. Just create your tablespace.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.CreatingTablespacesAndDatafiles

> When creating data files and log files you cannot specify physical file names.